# What is the probability that the sum of points is equal to $6$ or the product is even number when we are rolling two dices?

Tags: probability

> What is the probability that the sum of points is equal to $6$ or the
>   product is even number when we are rolling two dices?

$P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$

$P(A)=\dfrac{5}{36}$ and $P(B)=\dfrac{9}{36}$. How can I find the probability of $P(A \cap B)$? What is the number of all cases?

Comment: Only possible outcomes with sum $6$ and product even are $(2,4)$ and $(4,2)$.

Comment: What about $(3,3)$?

Comment: You have asked a question about $P(A \cap B)$ so you want the product to be even, right? My comment is not about $P(A \cup B)$.

Comment: So, what's the probability? I really don't get it.

Comment: $P(A\cap B)=\frac 1 {36}+\frac 1 {36}=\frac  1 {18}$. Just put this value in you formula to find $P(A \cup B)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we colour in red the set of all pairs whose sum is $6$, and if we colour in blue the set of all pairs whose product is even, (and purple represents both) then observe that:
$$
\textsf{SampleSpace} =
\begin{Bmatrix} 
(1, 1), & \color{blue}{(1, 2)}, & (1, 3), & \color{blue}{(1, 4)}, & \color{red}{(1, 5)}, & \color{blue}{(1, 6)}, \\
\color{blue}{(2, 1)}, & \color{blue}{(2, 2)}, & \color{blue}{(2, 3)}, & \color{purple}{(2, 4)}, & \color{blue}{(2, 5)}, & \color{blue}{(2, 6)}, \\
(3, 1), & \color{blue}{(3, 2)}, & \color{red}{(3, 3)}, & \color{blue}{(3, 4)}, & (3, 5), & \color{blue}{(3, 6)}, \\
\color{blue}{(4, 1)}, & \color{purple}{(4, 2)}, & \color{blue}{(4, 3)}, & \color{blue}{(4, 4)}, & \color{blue}{(4, 5)}, & \color{blue}{(4, 6)}, \\
\color{red}{(5, 1)}, & \color{blue}{(5, 2)}, & (5, 3), & \color{blue}{(5, 4)}, & (5, 5), & \color{blue}{(5, 6)}, \\
\color{blue}{(6, 1)}, & \color{blue}{(6, 2)}, & \color{blue}{(6, 3)}, & \color{blue}{(6, 4)}, & \color{blue}{(6, 5)}, & \color{blue}{(6, 6)} \\
\end{Bmatrix}
$$
So how many pairs are coloured red, blue, or both (i.e.: purple)?